# Breakpoint / responsive plugins for Vue 3

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, vuejs3

Building an enterprise level application with Vue 3 and unfortunately I haven't found any suitable plugin to make the application responsive. While there are older plugins that work with Vue 2, nothing I have found works with Vue-3.

What would be a suitable approach to make the application responsive?

Comment: .. media queries ?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming CSS media queries aren't enough I would honestly just use the [matchMedia](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/matchMedia) API.
You could react to window resizes with a `MediaQueryList` [onchange handler](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaQueryList/onchange).

Answer (score 0):

I decided to write a tiny plugin focused on ease of use and runtime performance: [vue-responsiveness](https://github.com/andrei-gheorghiu/vue-responsiveness).

```
yarn add vue-responsiveness
```

```js
import { VueResponsiveness } from 'vue-responsiveness'

createApp(App)
  .use(VueResponsiveness, {
    xs: 0,
    sm: 600,
    md: 960,
    lg: 1260,
    xl: 1920
  })
  .mount('#app')
```

Provides an app-wide `$matches[key][value]`, which can be used to show/hide things responsively.

- `key` is one of the config object's keys
- `value` is `min`, `max` or `only`, all `boolean`.

Usage examples (for the above config):

```html
<template v-if="$matches.sm.min">
  <!-- @media (min-width: 600px) -->
   ...content
</template>

<SomeComponent v-if="$matches.sm.max">
  <!-- @media (max-width: 959.9px) -->
  ...content
</SomeComponent>

<div v-if="$matches.sm.only">
  <!-- @media (min-width: 600px) and (max-width: 959.9px) -->
  ...content
</div>
```

Basic demo: https://codesandbox.io/p/devbox/nxqvcr

---

Usage in Composition API (`setup`):

```js
import { useMatches } from 'vue-responsiveness'

const matches = useMatches() // reactive object
```

Usage in Options API:

```js
export default {
  computed: {
    isSmAndUp() {
      return this.$matches.sm.min
    }
  },
  methods: {
   logCurrentInterval() {
     console.log(this.$matches.current)
   }
  }
}
```

---

Comes with presets for popular CSS frameworks, so you don't have to spend time figuring out their responsiveness breakpoints:

```js
import { VueResponsiveness, Presets } from 'vue-responsiveness'

//...
   .use(VueResponsiveness, Presets.Tailwind_CSS)
//...
```

Available presets: `Bootstrap_3`, `Bootstrap_4`, `Bootstrap_5`, `Bulma`, `Chakra`, `Foundation`, `Ionic`, `Material_Design`, `Materialize`, `Material_UI`, `Quasar`, `Semantic_UI`, `Skeleton`, `Tailwind_CSS`, `Vuetify`, `Windi_CSS`

TypeScript friendly (written in TS), it should get proper code hinting and linting in any decent IDE.

---

Hope you'll find it useful.